# How to I match an X window id to a parent process id in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, xorg, process

I have a script which manipulates windows using `wmctrl`.

It basically works but there's a race condition. When an arbitrary program is launched, I need to determine its X window ID. The naive version is basically

```
 wmctl -l | cut -d ' ' -f 1 >before

 do
     wmctl -l | cut -d ' ' -f 1 >after
 until diff before after reveals a new line
```

The bash script containing the above logic knows the PID of the child process which was launched. The child process forks, the grandchild creates an X window id, and the child dies.

I have the PID of the child and the X window ID of the candidate grandchild's window. I do not have the PIDs of any intermediate processes.

I can't synchronise window creation or modify the child program itself, so to evade the race condition, I need to verify that the candidate X window ID is derived from the now-dead child process. How do I do this?

Comment: If the child process is dead and reaped, then the grandchild's PPID will be 1 anyway, so I'm not sure if this is possible?

Comment: Also, you might find [this](https://gist.github.com/grawity/03ce2b1c37cff5578610555d088a7ca9) a bit more useful